# How to make a edit text which has a limit of char and ignores all the chars of a url

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can we make a custom edit text that will have a limit, for example, 300 chars? But, if the users enter a very long link like 200 chars, how can I reduce the chars for the link? For example:

```
User entered: Hello, world.
Length: 13

User entered: Hello https://stackoverflow.com
Length: 7 // adding only one char for a url
```

---

*This is a self-answer-based question as I felt this is a common need for people. I have added the code in both java and kotlin*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code for works fine for java:

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Patterns;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CustomEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    private int charCount = 0;

    public CustomEdiText(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
        super(context, set);
    }

    public CustomEdiText(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
        List<String> urls = extractUrls(text.toString());

        String removedText = text.toString();
        if(urls.size() != 0){
            for (String mText: urls) {
                removedText = text.toString().replaceAll(mText," ");
            }
            charCount = removedText.length();
            return;
        }

        charCount = text.toString().length();
    }

    public int getCharCount(){
        return charCount;
    }

    private List<String> extractUrls(String input) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] words = input.split("\\s+");

        Pattern pattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;
        for(String word : words)
            if (pattern.matcher(word).find())
                result.add(word);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text, type);
        List<String> urls = extractUrls(text.toString());

        String removedText = text.toString();
        if(urls.size() != 0){
            for (String mText: urls) {
                removedText = text.toString().replaceAll(mText," "); // 1 space as I want url to be one char on counting
            }
            charCount = removedText.length();
            return;
        }

        charCount = text.toString().length();
    }
}
```

You can use it just as a normal edit text class.

To get the length, you can call :

```
editText.getCharCount();
```

Don't use .length() or you will get wrong result

Also, the Kotlin code:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Patterns
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText


class CustomEditText(context: Context) : AppCompatEditText(context) {
    var charCount = 0
        private set

    override fun onTextChanged(
        text: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        lengthBefore: Int,
        lengthAfter: Int
    ) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter)
        val urls = extractUrls(text.toString())
        var removedText = text.toString()
        if (urls.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (mText in urls) {
                removedText = text.toString().replace(mText.toRegex(), " ")
            }
            charCount = removedText.length
            return
        }
        charCount = text.toString().length
    }

    private fun extractUrls(input: String): List<String> {
        val result: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        val words = input.split("\\s+").toTypedArray()
        val pattern = Patterns.WEB_URL
        for (word in words) if (pattern.matcher(word).find()) result.add(word)
        return result
    }

    override fun setText(text: CharSequence, type: BufferType) {
        super.setText(text, type)
        val urls = extractUrls(text.toString())
        var removedText = text.toString()
        if (urls.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (mText in urls) {
                removedText = text.toString().replace(
                    mText.toRegex(),
                    " " // 1 space as I want url to be one char on counting
                )
            }
            charCount = removedText.length
            return
        }
        charCount = text.toString().length
    }
}
```

Same way, you can call

```
editText.charCount
```